# Retrieve details of a particular vendor with the LIstID of that vendor in QuickBooks using their SDK in C#?

Tags: quickbooks

How do I query the QuickBooks to get the details of a particular vendor with the ListID of that vendor.?
I only have the ListID of that Vendor. How do I query with ListID? I checked the SDK and found that there was IVendorQuery method, which can be used to query a particular vendor. But I could not find a way to passs the ListID to that method to get the details.

What I am currently doing is to retrieve all the vendors from QuickBooks, then trying to match their ListID with the ListID I need using a for loop. It is something like this,

```
IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
IResponse response = responseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
IVendorRetList vendorRetList = (IVendorRetList)response.Detail;
if (vendorRetList != null)
{
 for (int j = 0; j < vendorRetList.Count; j++)
 {
  IVendorRet vendorRet = vendorRetList.GetAt(j);
  if (dvVendors.GetRowCellValue(i, "ListID").ToString() == vendorRet.ListID.GetValue())
  {
   strSeqId = vendorRet.EditSequence.GetValue();
   //code to edit that vendor using edit sequence id
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this page in the section "Querying QB and Making Sense of the Result".

http://www.mad-computer-scientist.com/blog/2008/03/25/quickbooks-integration/

Specifically, if the filter doesn't exist in the list of filters available at:

```
IVendorQuery.ORVendorListQuery.VendorListFilter
```

then it doesn't exist and you are stuck with querying as you have already done in your original question.